# Running the below code to prevent changes once data have been entered into selected cells in an excel worksheet is producing vba error 424

Tags: excel, vba

Running the below code to prevent changes once data have been entered into selected cells in an excel worksheet is producing vba error 424. I will appreciate any help with this.

```
 Sub Protect data()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
    Target.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use space in sub name.

Comment: Use you codes in `sheet_chnage` event.

Comment: What is `Target` here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.